# how can scan bluetooth devices using core bluetooth sdk?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm currently creating an iPhone app (Xcode 6.2, IOS 8.2) that could use Bluetooth devices! Main goal of this application is only search the available bluetooth devices and whenever you go to out of range from bluetooth devices one alert message pop up.and when ever you come in range automatically connected.

The only solution I see here (to keep my app on AppStore) is to try scan for available bluetooth devices!

I tried to use CoreBluetooth framework, but I don't get list of available devices!
I wants to hit my head on my monitor i am very frustrated with this problem.

My code is here:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
 #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

 @interface ViewController ()     <CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
CBCentralManager *mgr;
CBPeripheralManager *manager;

 }

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

mgr = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
manager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
NSString *messtoshow;

switch (central.state) {
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"State unknown, update imminent."];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy"];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy"];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered off."];
         NSLog(@"%@",messtoshow);
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
    {

        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."];

        [mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey :@YES}];

        NSLog(@"%@",messtoshow);
        break;

    }
}
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {


NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[advertisementData description]]);

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Discover:%@,RSSI:%@\n",[advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataLocalName"],RSSI]);
NSLog(@"Discovered %@", peripheral.name);
[mgr  connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

didDiscoverPeripheral method successfully called But shows only one device,i show you Log:

```
2015-03-27 17:10:48.137 StanBluetooth[853:109794] Discover:(null),RSSI:-68

2015-03-27 17:10:48.138 StanBluetooth[853:109794] Discovered peripheral E876A182-9DC1-26B4-3C89-DD20F5EAE88B

2015-03-27 17:10:48.139 StanBluetooth[853:109794] Discovered Amit’s MacBook Air

2015-03-27 17:10:48.140 StanBluetooth[853:109794] {
kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
}
```

i am trying to find another device last 2 days.

any advice would be appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Refer Apple's sample code from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927 "here").

Comment: Are there any BLE peripherals around you?  Have you tried the LightBlue app from the app store to verify?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes two BLE peripherals available. yes i had already tried Light Blue app.

Comment: Your log shows discovery of two devices - *E876A182-9DC1-26B4-3C89-DD20F5EAE88B* and *Amit’s MacBook Air*

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok this is two device then why does not show this UDID E876A182-9DC1-26B4-3C89-DD20F5EAE88B  device name.

Comment: I don't know but your log is inconsistent with your code. You have two "discovered" but only one of each other log message. Your code looks generally ok.

Comment: This code is meant to demonstrate CoreBluetooth in the background but is a general purpose BLE scanner. Perhaps it will help - https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: @Paulw11 i use to your code i wants to scan this way  NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"02210893-8f12-4278-83f9-f29e71f30fc0"]];[mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey :@YES}]; but didDiscoverPeripheral is not called.

Comment: Is your peripheral definitely advertising that service?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes definitely.

Comment: What if you scan using nil? Is your peripheral discovered?  Can LightBlue connect to your peripheral? The code you have shown looks ok. It is pointing at your peripheral being an issue. Is it another iOS device or something else?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes here is 1 imac and two another macmini and 1 iphone4 and 1 iphone5s but does not retrieve any devices. i wait 10 to 15 min.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok forgot these all things only you suggest me can i retrieve the connected bluetooth devices in my app?

Comment: All of those devices will require you to run an app in order to provide a connectable service

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.

Some hints on why the second device might not appear:

- If you found the second device using another 3rd party iOS Bluetooth scanning app like [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8), it might have connected to that device (if you tapped on it to get more details). When a peripheral device is connected to, very often, it stops advertising (connection establishment is usually the sole reason for advertising). If the device is not advertising any more, you cannot find it by scanning. If this is the case and the device is already connected to the iOS device, you could use `CBCentralManager`'s methods `-retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:` or `-retrieveConnectedPeripherals` (deprecated since iOS 7) to get the peripherals that have already been connected to iOS by another app.
- The peripheral might be advertising at such a slow rate, that it just takes a really long time (and a bit of luck) to be found by the iOS device. If this is the case, try picking a shorter advertising interval on your peripheral (assuming you control the firmware of the peripheral).

Note you do not need the `CBPeripheralManager` if you only need to scan for other peripherals.

Comment: @Martinjn i used to retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices but this method is not called. i am calling to this way   NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"02210893-8f12-4278-83f9-f29e71f30fc0"]];     [mgr retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:services];

Comment: @Martinjn i am try to call another way  [self.mgr retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:services]; 
and use to this delegate method 
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals{
    
    NSLog(@"didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals called");
    for (CBPeripheral *a in peripherals){
        NSLog(a.name); 
    }
}