# how to scan available beacons in my region iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ibeacon

I am new to beacon coding.
Our client want a app which will scan all the available beacon devices (manufactured by client itself)

I want to write a generic code which will scan for all available devices near by, and will show me alert on particular command,
like it will blow GREEN light when call is there, Yellow light when Message received etc.
I have the commands provided, but need a methods for beacon to call those commands, in iOS.

first target is to scan all available devices.

On sample I found some tutorials which are providing direct UUID
but I need to generate a code which will scan all.

any links and other info is welcome.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can [LAN Scan](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan) help?

Comment: Firstly, are they beacons or just BLE devices?  Beacons advertise a UUID and two 16 bit numbers called the major and minor values.  You can easily create an app that scans for a particular beacon UUID using CLBeaconRegion in Core Location.  Your mention of other attributes suggests that these aren't beacons and are in fact Bluetooth Low Energy Peripherals.  These are handled through Core Bluetooth.  Again you can create an app to scan for a particular BLE service, but you need to provide more information on your problem and what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple restricts the ability to scan for iBeacons on iOS so that you must know the beacons' ProximityUUIDs up front.  **There is no way to simply scan for all iBeacons regardless of ProximityUUID using public APIs.**  While there are private API hacks that may allow this, these will not allow the app to be approved for distribution in the AppStore.

**If you can get a finite list of known ProximityUUIDs for your client, this will still work OK.**  You can call CoreLocation's `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` command multiple times, once for each ProxinityUUID.   While there is no hard limit on the number of times you can call this (unlike monitoring APIs which have a limit of 20 regions), practically you can probably only call this in the low hundreds of times.

Bottom line: while you cannot scan for all beacons regardless of ProxinityUUID, you can get close to the same effect if you know all the UUIDs up front.

Comment: Thanks fir the info and solution @davidgyoung, will try to get ProximityUUID. for this I am using this link, Hope it will work. what you say.....? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299592/how-can-scan-bluetooth-devices-using-core-bluetooth-sdk